# Not able to use Date filed in Parcelable class in android

Tags: android, parcelable

I am working in an android project and I want to pass a List of object from once activity to another activity . In the object there are Date fields too.. I have implemented my class with Parcelable to pass my List of Object from one activity and I am not not to parse my Date field. So please suggest me a solution.

This is the class I want to pass

```
public class Consumer {

    public int BusClientLogID;
    public int ClientID;
    public String ClientName;
    public int ClientStatus;
    public int Client_GroupStatus;
    public String EmployeeName;
    public String ServiceCompletedCount;
    public Date SignInTime;
    public Date TimeArrive;
    public Date TimeDepart;
    public Date SignOutTime;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively you can use `long` and then convert it to `Date` and back. Here is an example showing how you can do it for SignInTime field.

```
public class Consumer implements Parcelable {

    public long SignInTime;

    public Consumer(Parcel in) {
        SignInTime = in.readLong();
    }

    public Date getSignInTime() {
        return new Date(SignInTime);
    }

    public void setSignInTime(Date date) {
        SignInTime = date.getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(SignInTime);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I convert...Any sample code to convert it

Comment: I added an example to the answer